# How to add constraints to a label inside of a UICollectionViewCell?

Tags: ios, uilabel, uicollectionviewcell, centering, nslayoutconstraint

I have a `UILabel`

```
var cellTitle = UILabel()
```

I have a `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method where I declare a cell with the identifier and I add constraints to a label I created named `cellTitle`:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell
    cellTitle = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.bounds.size.width, 160))
    cellTitle.numberOfLines = 3
    cell.contentView.addSubview(cellTitle)
    cell.addConstraints([
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: cell, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: cellTitle, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0),
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: cell, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: cellTitle, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
    ])
}
```

I get this error when I run the simulator:

Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(

```
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7baaac40 UICollectionViewCell:0x7b981570.centerY == UILabel:0x7baa3dd0'Towed by smaller boats, c...'.centerY>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7baa5c70 h=--& v=--& UILabel:0x7baa3dd0'Towed by smaller boats, c...'.midY == + 80>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7baa5d50 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UICollectionViewCell:0x7b981570(210)]>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7bab1110 h=--- v=--- 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Top' V:[UICollectionViewCell:0x7b981570]-(0)-|>"
```

)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint

In the part where I use the `addConstraints` method, I clearly am trying to center the label in the cell. For some reason the label isn't becoming centered in the cell:

[image: containerView cells with label]

What can I do to fix this? I appreciate any support.

Comment: Make sure the label's text alignment is Center

Comment: @milesper it isn't. How can I center the alignment of the text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the text in the label is aligned to the center.  It appears to be aligned to the left, though the label itself is centered.

```
cellLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
```

In swift it would be:

```
cellLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
```

Or just

```
cellLabel.textAlignment = .center
```

Comment: I tried that in my `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method, but I get an error on that line: `Use of unresolved identifier 'NSTextAlignmentCenter'`, perhaps that is Objective C? (I am new to programming)

Comment: There added the Swift equivalent

Comment: In SWIFT, it's giving me an error on upper case 'c' of center. But works with lower case 'c'.